# In Swift 5, How to convert a Float to a String localized in order to display it in a textField?

Tags: swift, localization, nsnumber, numberformatter

I need to convert a Float to a localized String.
i write this function which is an extension from Float:

```
 func afficherUnFloat() -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        //numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        //numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 6
        
        if let result = numberFormatter.number(from: self) {
            return numberFormatter.string(for: result) ?? "0"
        }
        return "0"
    }
```

but it didn't work:
Here is the exemple

```
let xxx : Float =  111.222
        myTextField.text = String(xxx).afficherUnFloat()
```

I have installed a pod KSNumericTextField, that limit the numbers in the textfield. He display it only if it is locally formatted.

When i run the app, it doesn't diplay 111,222 in a french region, or 111,222 in an arabic one.
nothing is dislpayed

Comment: Why format in an extension and if so why not an extension to Float?

Comment: sorry i want to say an extension of Float

Comment: So skip the if let... and replace it with `return numberFormatter.string(for: self) ?? "0` to get code that compiles and returns the right thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is finaly a solution:

```
extension Float {
    
    func afficherUnFloat() -> String {
        let text : NSNumber = self as NSNumber
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.locale = .current
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ""
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2 // your choice
        numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 6 // your choice

        let result = numberFormatter.string(from: text) ?? ""
            return result
    }
    
}
```

With this, you can format every Float to a localized String, compatible with the keyboard choosen by the user, regardless of his locality or langage.
There is no need to force a special keyboard to have a specific decimal separator.

you can use it like this:

```
let myFloat: Float = 111.222
let myString :String = myFloat.afficherUnFloat()
```

myString will be displayed as the location requires

Comment: Note that there is no need to cast your `Float` to `NSNumber`. You can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` instead of NumberFormatter's method `string(from: NSNumber)`. Btw it will create a new number formatter every time you call this property

Comment: @Leo in the begging i didn't cast it. and the textfield with the pod displayed nothing. You are right, there are more than one solution, specially after a long time of searching

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no need to cast your Float to NSNumber. You can use Formatter's method string(for: Any) instead of NumberFormatter's method string(from: NSNumber). Btw it will create a new number formatter every time you call this property. I would make your formatter static:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let decimal: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.locale = .current
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2 // your choice
        numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 6 // your choice
        return numberFormatter
    }()
}
extension FloatingPoint {
    var afficherUnFloat: String { Formatter.decimal.string(for: self) ?? "" }
}

let float: Float = 111.222
let string = float.afficherUnFloat // "111.22"
```

Comment: if there is a pod that control the format, you need to add the grouping separator's model too

Comment: you can still change it just calling `Formatter.decimal.whatever = ...`